# AJAX "parsererror", "No conversion from text to application/json"

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I tried to post a JSON using simple *AJAX client* and using php as *restful server*. But I am parsing this json it shows the error.

> **ERROR:"parsererror", "No conversion from text to application/json"**

My client code is,

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>The jQuery Example</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#driver").click(function(event){

            var person = {
            name: 'df',
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: './ajax.php',
                dataType: "application/json",
                //contentType: "json",
                type:'post',
                data: person,//{'FirstName':FirstName,'LastName':LastName},
                success: function(msg) {
                      alert(msg);
                    },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
            });

            });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="stage" style="background-color:cc0;">
         STAGE
      </div>
      <input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" />
   </body>
</html>
```

And my server code is,

```
<?php


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") {


} else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $jsonData = file_get_contents('php://input');

    echo $jsonData;
    //echo "true";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `exit` at the end of the logic, try the below:

```
<?php


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") {
    ...

} else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $jsonData = file_get_contents('php://input');

    echo $jsonData;
    //echo "true";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: What exactly does this exit do?